# Magento 2.1 "Styles.css" standatd file missing, instead css data pulled from "%7B%7BMEDIA_URL%7D%7Dstyles.css"

Tags: magento-2.1, css

Good day, thank you in advance for the advice.

During struggles in establishing some elements that use standard .css, I noticed that instead of standard "Styles.css" file the commands are pulled from strange location/file:
http://magento.myDomain.com/%7B%7BMEDIA_URL%7D%7Dstyles.css (and styles.css file missing)

When I tried to open/edit with the help of firebug (FF), I got the text "There are no rules. You can create a rule." I could place standard .css code what solved my issues on the browser view (and shows that the location would be right).

Never the less, I can't find the file or spot a field in Magento CMS to insert the CSS code.

Any advise wherefrom data is pulled for file "%7B%7BMEDIA_URL%7D%7Dstyles.css" or where the file is placed?

For me, it looks like some Magento CMS generated file.. and I have to clue where the field to edit it is placed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That CSS never gonna be used in magento. You can simply remove that or comment that line from

> Content > Design > Configuration > Select Theme > HTML Head section > Scripts and Style Sheets

Now, you can add your CSS files in head_blocks.xml

CHEERS =)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this file in admin.

Navigate to **Content** > **Design** > **Configuration** > Select Theme > **HTML Head** section > **Scripts and Style Sheets** field

Comment: Great. I inserted the following script piece: "<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="styles.css" />" and placed style sheet in root folder. Now it worked. After I tried to change button color in footer (subscribe), but it did not work... are the style sheets managed differently in that way.

Comment: if i replaced by this code "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles.css" />" its not working, how can i solve my issue.

Comment: How to do this from code, because of my website blank page and return error => https://snipboard.io/BRguA7.jpg